# Invalidating previous Json Web Tokens when changing user details

Tags: javascript, express, session, jwt, session-cookies

Currently, after a user logs in with their username and password, they retrieve an `access_token` with the `payload` holding their `uniqueTokenIdentifier` which is stored uniquely for every user in the database.

When a user changes their password, for example if their account has been hacked, their password is successfully updated in the database, however **also** a new `uniqueTokenIdentifier` is set in the database for that particular user. That means that any request a malicious user sends with the **old** access token containing the **old** `uniqueTokenIdentifier` will not return any data relating to that particular user. E.g that particular users messages, as the `uniqueTokenIdentifier` has been updated

In addition to this, any further requests made with the old `access_token` would result in a **403 forbidden error**, as no user in the database would exist with this `uniqueTokenIdentifier` .

This method is used to handle the case where an account has been hacked, and the user needs to change their password in order to secure the account. After researching solutions related to this issue, I discovered a `token blacklist` method, which keeps track of all tokens which have been revoked. However, I didn't discover any answers relating to this method described above, therefore are there any potential issues with this solution? Perhaps it's bad practise due to security risks, and I am unaware of these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i mean, what you're talking about wanting to do is invalidate a token.  This can be done any number of ways:

- blacklist (not exactly great, because now you're holding on to it forever)
- setting a TTL in the past (so it expires naturally)
- manually removing the token from the storage (if that's how you're doing it)

I mean, the answer to this also depends on how you store it:

- DB?
- memory/file cache?
- session?
- cookie (... =\ )
- filesystem
- etc.

each one of the above is going to have its own "best practices".  There is no "best" solution though unless you understand use cases and what you have at your disposal.

tldr; more information needed before anyone can help you with this.

technically though, your algorithms that you use for checking for validation should always properly handle both invalid and valid tokens regardless.

if it still validates an invalid/old token *all because it matches some pattern or satisfies a requirement* then I would say you need to rethink your authentication strategy in general as you're open to all sorts of relay and man-in-the-middle attacks.  You aren't alone with this sort of problem though as it exists with more applications than you might think.

I'm not suggesting you do this, but merely giving you an example of what has worked for me in the past with a use case specific to the company I worked for at the time.

The way we always handled tokens (and I hate tokens honestly) was tokens were stored in a memory store with a TTL.  Once the TTL was met (or the user manually logged out, or their demographics changed or *enter all sorts of reasons here*), the token was removed from the store.

In the case that you're talking about, what we would do is either remove the token from the store or set the TTL to some date/time in the past so that the cleanup process would remove it (it also meant that the next time the token was used, it would be considered invalid as the TTL had been met - and the backend would clean it automatically).

Again, without knowing your person use case though its hard to understand what would work best for you.  The above is not the only approach either and others exist.

FWIW, hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so just so I understand correctly, the solution you're talking about involved the following. After a user logs in, store their token in a in memory store with a TTL. Whenever the token expires or a user changes their password for example, remove it or invalidate it in the store, meaning any further requests **made with this particular token** will not work. Is this correct?

Comment: In addition to this, could you please give me some examples of how I would handle a user logging in with one account on multiple devices? Would I have to store multiple tokens per user? If so, how would I handle this scenario when a user gets their tokens (refresh and access token) stolen by a malicious user? Thanks